# Proteus burnout LED

Tags: simulation, proteus

I have been used tinkercad.com for circuit and Arduino simulations.
I'm moving now to Proteus as I'm trying to get more advanced
My first simple circuit in Proteus was a 9v battery and a LED, I ran the simulator and I expected the LED to burn out the same as I'm used to in tinkercad, but it didn't.
what am I missing?

**tinkercad.com**
[image]

**Proteus**
[image]

Comment: Proteus doesn't have any facility for simulating thermal considerations (and I suspect tinkercad doesn't either, and just uses some overly simplistic way of determining when a part is overloaded), so it can't tell when your part will fail. In fact, I've never seen any professional circuit simulation software that does have parts "fail", because simulating part failure *properly* is an incredibly hard problem.

Comment: I think Pspice has something called smoke analysis, but of course you have to define the maximum limits for each component.

Comment: Professional simulators rarely have smoke emitting diodes and flashy effects. You would have to ask Proteus why their simulator does not have such important feature missing. We can only guess and give opinions why it would be so.

Comment: It should at least give a warning that it is too much current..

Comment: monitor the current

Comment: microcap v12 have smoke analysis and it is free. http://www.spectrum-soft.com/index.shtm